# Heroku stuck at Building Source for Django app

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I have successfully pushed the previous versions of my Django app to Heroku. It usually shows some errors if it is not able to deploy, but this time it is stuck at this for about an hour:

```
Counting objects: 10977, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7719/7719), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10977/10977), 17.29 MiB | 3.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 10977 (delta 3954), reused 6832 (delta 2062)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
```

Here's the GitHub link to the app that I am trying to deploy: https://github.com/surajsjain/smart-aquaponics-backend

Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi seems you just posted this question! I also encountered this issue and get frustrated because I have tried anything I can do but none worked. Seems it's heroku's issue?

Comment: I can confirm it is a Heroku issue. tried all alternatives.

Comment: Yes, it's an issue with Heroku. It got fixed by itself after a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me. 
I think it's a heroku bug from server and to cancel the build in progress:
install the heroku plugin 'heroku-builds'

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
```

then you can stop the building:

```
heroku builds:cancel -a "Here put the name of your app"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's on Heroku's end. I have the same problem, and so does this guy [Heroku Stuck at Building Source for NodeJs App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739096/heroku-stuck-at-building-source-for-nodejs-app)

You might want to contact Heroku CS now...

What I've done:

- Canceled the build and try again 3 times -> no luck.
- Put my app into maintenance mode -> it did NOT go offline!
- Turned off any existing workers -> it did NOT go offline either!

Comment: Mine is a nodejs REST API and I found it not working just now. I even deleted my app and recreate it and now it stuck in Building source process.

Comment: @AlexWang I tried deleting and recreating my app too. I think it's an issue with Heroku too.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me. Definitely, an error from Heroku side.