# Heroku Stuck at Building Source for NodeJs App

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, bitbucket, heroku-cli

When I tried to deploy my app on heroku, it gets stuck at remote: Building source

I initially thought it was network and changed network, but the issue persists then, I also tried force push, that didn't work either

````
Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.36 KiB | 39.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: ```
````

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is happening every now and then. Aside from you and me being stuck at building source, there's another guy here [Heroku stuck at Building Source for Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738911/heroku-stuck-at-building-source-for-django-app)

I guess it's best to contact Heroku CS now...

Comment: Yea, I agree, looks like it's a problem from heroku

Comment: Yes, I'm also stuck at building =\

Comment: Yes! i am stuck at building as well

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It seems like it's an issue from Heroku.
You can see updates here : https://status.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

This also happened during my Heroku push.

I just `CTRL-c` and tried again with no problem except for a warning from Heroku that said `remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ...` which you can safely ignore.